# How can I autowire a service that is imported from another jar?

Tags: java, spring

I have a jar file that contains a java class `HelloService` with `@Service` annotation. I would like to Autowire it into my a `@Component` class `GoodByeComponent` that I am writing (autowire into the constructor).

So, the skeleton for `HelloService` could look something like this:

```
@Service
public class HelloService
{
    ...
}
```

And the `GoodByeComponent` would look like:

```
import from.some.jar.HelloService

@Component
public class GoodByeComponent
{
    private final HelloService helloService;

    @Autowired
    public GoodByeComponent(HelloService helloService)
    {
        this.helloService = helloService;
    }
}
```

Understandably, I get an error that says `Could not autowire. No beans of 'HelloService' type found.`

So. I have some idea that I might need to create a bean somewhere that returns `HelloService`? How would I even instantiate the service...? It also needs to autowire other things. Is this possible, or is it too much of a headache and I should probably just copy it into my jar?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, but I imagine you need your Spring application to find and scan the files you're importing. If Spring doesn't pick up the file then it won't be created as a bean. You don't need to instantiate HelloService since it is marked as a Service and therefore will be made into a bean which you can auto wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question does not have enough information, but most likely, your application have a `@ComponentScan` annotation somewhere in your program. That annotation is responsible for finding your `@Component`, `@Service` and initializing them.

By default, `@ComponentScan` only scan for the its own package. So let say it you have a package structure similar to this:

```
your.own.package ---- ConfigurationClass
                  |
                  --- GoodByeComponent
```

Then spring naturally, will only discover the `GoodByeComponent` and cannot find the `HelloService`.

You have to supply additional location for it like:

`@ComponentScan({ "your.own.package", "from.some.jar" })`

That would allow spring to discover the beans inside your own application, as well as the external dependency you rely on.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. That worked! For those wondering, I did *not* explicitly have a `ComponentScan` annotation, but did have a `SpringBootApplication` annotation, which auto uses it. So if anyone reading this answer in the future can't find it, know it's there, it's just in there. Adding it normally to the Application class overrides the one in `SprintBootApplication`